# practically verifying block ciphers strength

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher

How do we verify practically the strength of a block ciphers? Most of the security analysis of block ciphers is usually around theoretical analysis and proofs in some random oracle model etc.

For example, for our recently designed [FNR encryption](https://github.com/sashank/libfnr) scheme, we have only given results based on previously done theoretical work by Naor and Reingold. That is 
if $r$ is round count, $n$ is number of bits of input domain, $m$ is number of queries an attacker needs to make, then the security measure for FNR, is defined as below.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& ( r/2 * m^2 /  2^{(1- 1/r)* n }) \; \textit{ where r $\geq$ 4 } 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But how do we practically verify this by experimental results? What about cryptanalysis tools?

 
I believe such tools would help any one who is designing block ciphers in general.

Comment: Hint: GitHub readme says “FNR is a small domain block cipher to encrypt…” while [line 2 of fnr.c](http://goo.gl/2xYjU6) says “FNR is a small domain block cipher **mode** to encrypt…” which is more correct since you’re using OpenSSL’s AES-128 in ECB mode as a cipher base, wrapping your "Flexible Naor and Reingold" mode ([line 4](http://goo.gl/2xYjU6)) around that. Same for your question here: you don’t need tools to test the block cipher (which is AES), you actually need tools to analyze your *“block cipher **mode**”*. Analyzing block ciphers is not really the same as analyzing cipher *modes*.

Comment: it is a encryption scheme not mode, shall correct it thanks ! BTW , curious what those tools are for analyzing "modes"

Comment: /* No need to thank me. */ As for tools, good question. Got no suggestions. http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/tools/ has “tools” but I’m not sure you can use any of it. Mostly I’ve seen people build their own stuff, but they rarely share it. And if they share things it’s a bunch of memory-leaking uselessness like [picek sbox tool](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Ege/files/picek_sbox_tool.zip) ([SIDES](http://sidesproject.wordpress.com/)) which is merely a thrown-together collection of code-snippets that doesn’t even match the description from [the paper they published](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~lejla/wistp14.pdf). :(

Comment: yes the tools could be lot generic. Am imagining, machine learning based say "supervised learning" based techniques to identify non-randomness after some number of rounds etc.

Comment: You could test non-randomness using a battery tester like DieHarder. But to gain some real cryptanalytic results, you should throw some checks for linear and for differential symptoms at it too (like analyzing correlation immunity, algebraic immunity, fixed points, propagation characteristics, etc.)! Since you’re using AES at FNR’s core, there shouldn’t be anything bad to show up on your radar… and that could provide a bit more confidence in the security of FNR. Yet, those are just ideas I’m throwing in here, meaning: there might be other ways to provide proof to FNR security as a scheme/mode.

Comment: I've voted to close as it is now impossible to tell what is asked by now. Asking for tool references seems to be off topic as well.